# Undefined method when accessing active record in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do rendering of @artclasses_mine.

This is what I have in the artclasses_controller - I access another model Cregistration.

```
  @array = Array.new
  Cregistration.where(cuser: current_user.email).find_each(batch_size: 50) do |i|
    @array[i] = Cregistration.cclass
  end  
  @artclasses_mine = Artclass.where( id: @array )
```

Then in the HTML file I do

```
    <%= render @artclasses_mine %>
```

The error I get is `"undefined method 'cclass' for #<Class"`

I realize that probably by using "where" I access the relation and not the actual record, so I tried

```
Cregistration.find_each(:batch_size => 50) do |i|
```

Still the same error

If I access the Cregistration model out of the loop, everything works fine.

I think the problem is with syntax, but I can not figure it out.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does the `cclass` attribute reference to? Is it an `artclass`'s id? Because the last line of your code is trying to find `Artclass` records where their id is in the array of `cclass` attribute values

Comment: `Cregistration.cclass` isn't going to work unless it's a class method. Odd choice for naming. You most likely need an instance to call that on depending on how it's defined. Is it an instance method or class method? Also, `cuser` is an attribute name where the value is an email?

Comment: Your code can be simplified to: `Artclass.where(id: Cregistration.where(cuser: current_user.email).limit(50).pluck(:cclass) )` but it makes no sense to store a artclass id in the cclass column of the Cregistration table.

Comment: MrYoshiji, it works, thank you! I need to adjust to the Ruby style - I am still writing as of the old school :) Thank you very much! The cclass id the field in the cregistration model to keep the cross-reference  - users vs art classes the registered to. I will work on my naming convention :) Thank again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access an instance method in a class object.

```
@array = []
Cregistration.where(cuser: current_user.email).limit(50).each do |reg|
  @array << reg.cclass
end
@artclasses_mine = Artclass.where(id: @array)
```

Here we talk to each instance as `reg` inside the loop and `push`/`<<` the `cclass` into the `@array`.